# How to run netsurf-fb? Fails with: "Unable to set video: Could not set console screen info fbdev"

Tags: framebuffer

On Ubuntu 16.04, I've done:

```
# Go to TTY with Ctrl + Alt + F1
sudo apt-get install netsurf-fb
sudo usermod -aG 'audio,input,video' "$USER"
# Logout, login.
netsurf-fb
```

And it fails with:

```
Unable to set video: Could not set console screen info fbdev
```

`sudo` didn't help either.

netsurf version 3.2.

`fbi` and `vlc` did work on the other hand.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I had a similar problem getting netsurf to run, but managed to fix it thanks to persistence and blind luck.

Problem 1: init mouse failed
Solution: Add myself to the input group (the group that owns /dev/input/mice

Problem 2: Unable to set video: Could not set console screen info fbdev
Solution: Install the xserver-xorg-video-fbdev and fbset packages

Problem 3: Running netsurf causes the screen to go blank and the system to hang, requiring a hard reboot
Solution: I ran it in verbose mode and redirected standard error to a file, and I saw that netsurf was complaining about not being able to find DejaVuSans.ttf. I copied the file from /usr/share/fonts/truetype/dejavu to /usr/share/netsurf

Comment: Wow, they need some serious packaging work there. Will try this if I'm feeling brave some time! :-)

Comment: @CiroSantilli709大抓捕六四事件法轮功: Correct. That has now been [filed as bug report in Debian](https://bugs.debian.org/867694).